# Dilemma over the possessive apostrophe

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe, possessive-s-vs-of

Punctuation question:

1. One of his friends house
2. One of his friend's house
3. One of his friends' house

Which is correct?

Answer (score 0):

**"One of his friends' house"** is the correct one.

Note: When **'One of'** acts as the subject of a clause it is followed by a plural noun and a singular verb.

**Possessive 's**:

singular noun + 's - His friend's house.

regular plural noun + ' - His friends' house.

irregular plural noun + 's - His children's house.

Comment: The explanation is correct, but most native English speakers would regard this as clumsy syntax, especially when spoken, as it requires the listener or reader to parse the phrase to make sure it is properly understood. It is much better, if slightly longer, to say or write **The house of one of his friends** - which is much more easily understood.